# How to rank GroupBy on Pyspark

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark

I want to rank GroupBy on Pyspark, I can do it in pandas, but I need to do this on PySpark

Here's my input

```
id      year  month date  hour  minute
54807   2021     12   31     6      29
54807   2021     12   31     6      31
54807   2021     12   31     7      15
54807   2021     12   31     7      30
```

Here's pandas code

```
df["rank"] = df.groupby(["id", "hour"])["minute"].rank()
```

Here's my output

```
id      year  month date  hour  minute  rank
54807   2021     12   31     6      29  1.0
54807   2021     12   31     6      31  2.0
54807   2021     12   31     7      15  1.0
54807   2021     12   31     7      30  2.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use a ranking window function - `rank`, `dense_rank`, `row_number`.

here's an example with `rank` window function.

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as func
from pyspark.sql.window import Window as wd

data_sdf. \
    withColumn('minute_rank', 
               func.rank().over(wd.partitionBy('id', 'year', 'month', 'date', 'hour').orderBy('minute'))
               ). \
    show()

# +-----+----+-----+----+----+------+-----------+
# |   id|year|month|date|hour|minute|minute_rank|
# +-----+----+-----+----+----+------+-----------+
# |54807|2021|   12|  31|   7|    15|          1|
# |54807|2021|   12|  31|   7|    30|          2|
# |54807|2021|   12|  31|   6|    29|          1|
# |54807|2021|   12|  31|   6|    31|          2|
# +-----+----+-----+----+----+------+-----------+
```